# Domain in marginal density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am so confused about the domain for marginal density of this problem...

Here is the joint density function :

$$
f(y_1,y_2) = \begin{cases} e^{-y_1} & 0\le y_2 \le y_1 \le \infty \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}
$$

Here is the solution:

[image]

I perfectly understand how we get those two marginal densities. What I don't understand is the domain for these two densities.

Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the joint density function, $\{(Y_1,Y_2):0\leq Y_2\leq Y_1 < \infty\}$, can be expressed as either:

- $\{\, (Y_1,Y_2) : Y_1\in [0,\infty), Y_2\in [0,Y_1] \,\}$
- $\{\, (Y_1,Y_2) : Y_2\in [0,\infty), Y_1\in [Y_2,\infty) \,\}$

Hence the limits for the marginal density functions.

---

To put it another way, to find the marginal density $f_1$ at $Y_1=y_1$, integrate over the support for $Y_2$ at that value, which is $0\leq Y_2\leq y_1$.

Likewise, to find the marginal density $f_2$ at $Y_2=y_2$, do so over the integrate over the support for $Y_1$ at that value, which is $y_2\leq Y_1 < \infty$.

Comment: Plainly you should have lower-case $y_1,y_2$ in the domains, given the way in which you're distinguishing between $y$ and $Y$ in the second paragraph.